# Entity Framework Link table with foreign keys to same table giving SQL error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have two tables for a data flow:

1. Component table that defines the attributes of the component in the dataflow with an Id as the primary key
2. Link table that connects the components by a From and To attribute.  The primary key is the From & To.

Here is the generated class for the component:

```
    [Table("Component")]
    public partial class Component
    {
        [Key]
        public int ComponentId { get; set; }
    
        public byte ComponentType { get; set; }
    
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        [Unicode(false)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    
        public int PackageId { get; set; }
    
        public int? OffsetX { get; set; }
    
        public int? OffsetY { get; set; }
    
        [InverseProperty("Component")]
        public virtual ICollection<Column> Columns { get; set; } = new List<Column>();
    
        [InverseProperty("FromComponent")]
        public virtual ICollection<ComponentLink> ComponentLinkFromComponents { get; set; } = new List<ComponentLink>();
    
        [InverseProperty("ToComponent")]
        public virtual ICollection<ComponentLink> ComponentLinkToComponents { get; set; } = new List<ComponentLink>();
    }
```

And the generated class for ComponentLink:

```
    [PrimaryKey("FromComponentId", "ToComponentId")]
    [Table("ComponentLink")]
    public partial class ComponentLink
    {
        [Key]
        public int FromComponentId { get; set; }
    
        [Key]
        public int ToComponentId { get; set; }
    
        public short FromSortIndex { get; set; }
    
        public short ToSortIndex { get; set; }
    
        [ForeignKey("FromComponentId")]
        [InverseProperty("ComponentLinkFromComponents")]
        public virtual Component FromComponent { get; set; }
    
        [ForeignKey("ToComponentId")]
        [InverseProperty("ComponentLinkToComponents")]
        public virtual Component ToComponent { get; set; }
    }
```

The following was generated in the DbContext in model.creating:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Component>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasOne(d => d.Package).WithMany(p => p.Components).HasConstraintName("FK_Component_Package");
            });
    
            modelBuilder.Entity<ComponentLink>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasOne(d => d.FromComponent).WithMany(p => p.ComponentLinkFromComponents)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_ComponentLink_FromComponent");
    
                entity.HasOne(d => d.ToComponent).WithMany(p => p.ComponentLinkToComponents).HasConstraintName("FK_ComponentLink_ToComponent");
            });
```

In my controller, I'm have the following LINQ query that gives an error:

```
    var query = db.Components
    .Include(c => c.ComponentLinkToComponents)
    .Include(c => c.ConditionalSplits)
    .Where(x => x.ComponentId == id || x.PackageId == PackageId)
    .ToList();
```

I get the following error:
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException HResult=0x80131904
Message=Invalid column name 'ComponentId'.
Invalid column name 'ComponentId1'.

I have Googled everything related to the shadow property '1' but don't see what is wrong with the code.

---

I added the HasKey:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<ComponentLink>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(x => new { x.FromComponentId, x.ToComponentId });
        entity.HasOne(d => d.FromComponent).WithMany(p => p.ComponentLinkFromComponents)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_ComponentLink_FromComponent");
       entity.HasOne(d => d.ToComponent).WithMany(p => p.ComponentLinkToComponents).HasConstraintName("FK_ComponentLink_ToComponent");
    });
```

I still get the error and the SQL in the Output window:

```
    SELECT [c].[ComponentId], [c].[ComponentType], [c].[Name], [c]. 
    [OffsetX], [c].[OffsetY], [c].[PackageId], [c0].[FromComponentId], 
    [c0].[ToComponentId], [c0].[ComponentId], [c0].[ComponentId1], 
    [c0].[FromSortIndex], [c0].[ToSortIndex], [c1].[ComponentId], [c1]. 
    [SortIndex], [c1].[Expression]
    FROM [Component] AS [c]
    LEFT JOIN [ComponentLink] AS [c0] ON [c].[ComponentId] = [c0]. 
    [ToComponentId]
    LEFT JOIN [ConditionalSplit] AS [c1] ON [c].[ComponentId] = [c1]. 
    [ComponentId]
    WHERE [c].[PackageId] = @__PackageId_1   
    ORDER BY [c].[ComponentId], [c0].[FromComponentId], [c0]. 
    [ToComponentId], [c1].[ComponentId]
```

Comment: I don't believe EF Core supports composite keys using the `[Key]` attribute like EF 6 did (requiring a `[Column Order=x]` attribute as well). Try defining the composite key on ComponentLink using the Fluent `HasKey(x => new { x.FromComponentId, x.ToComponentId});`

Comment: @StevePy I think you are correct that it has something to do with the composite key as you can see the shadow field in the SQL. Thanks.